# how to generate configure script -- linux

Tags: linux, configure

I have downloaded :--
libwebsockets-1.0-chrome25-firefox17

from ;--
http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/

I have to install websocket library. But it does not contains configure file.
As per install instruction :--

```
   The file `configure.ac' (or `configure.in') is used to create
`configure' by a program called `autoconf'.  You need `configure.ac' if
you want to change it or regenerate `configure' using a newer version
of `autoconf'.
```

Also it contains file :---
configure.ac
autogen.sh

Please suggest command to generate configure file, in linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the provided `autogen.sh` script.